# How to select value from Dropdown in Selenium when it is an input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu

Selection of Value from Dropdown in selenium webdriver when the type of dropdown is Input

Provided the XPath for the Dropdown clicked on it but not able to select values displayed.

Html for the Dropdown:

[image]

Value in Dropdown:

06/29/2019
[image]

Should be able to select any value form the Dropdown on the basis of User Input.

Comment: Please post your HTML in text format.Screenshot is very difficult to understand and provide the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Dynamic Xpath as below:

```
    String date = "06/22/2019";

    String Xpath = "//tr[@class='dxeListBoxItemRow_PDPSTheme']/tr[contains(.,'"+date+"')]";
```

Find element of dropdown click on in and then click on the element as per above xpath.
you also need to scroll down or focus the element first

here date is the input and as per your input the element will be selected

Comment: how same can be implemented in Page object model design Pattern with Factory